# How to stop listening and recv data from only one user and start listening again when he disconnects

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, network-protocols

I am trying to write a server-client program. The idea is that server

1. listens() on the given port
2. When a user connects it accepts() the connection and stops listening
3. On user disconnects, it goes back to listening state and this goes on forever.

Now, I have created the server and the communication is going fine, however, I am not sure how to stop listening when the user connects and start listening on disconnects. Can anyone help me with it?

Also, I am following beejs guide

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make the server to refuse connections from clients when it has accepted a connection is to `close(2)` the socket you use to `accept(2)` connections.

There's no possibility of making the kernel to reject connections on a one connection at a time.  The kernel only rejects a connection if there's no socket listening at it.

Below is a server example in which the accepting socket is closed between connections, so in case you start a second connection, the second one will get an `ECONNREFUSED` error.

But there's a race condition on this:  If a second connection happens to connect while the server program is in between the `accept(2)` and the `close(2)` system calls, the second connection will be opened (and closed) by the server with no error.  The client in the second connection will receive an eof from the server if it tries to `read(2)`, and an error if it tries to `write(2)` to the connection.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define F(_fmt) __FILE__":%d:%s: "_fmt, __LINE__, __func__
#define ERR(_ex_cod, _fmt, ...) do { \
        fprintf(stderr,              \
                F("ERROR: "_fmt),    \
                ##__VA_ARGS__);      \
        if (_ex_cod)                 \
            exit(_ex_cod);           \
    } while (0)

char *
sockaddr2str(
        struct sockaddr_in *addr,
        char *buf,
        size_t bufsz)
{
    char *ret_val = buf;
    snprintf(buf, bufsz,
            "%s:%d",
            inet_ntoa(addr->sin_addr),
            ntohs(addr->sin_port));
    return ret_val;
}

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(12345);

    for(;;) {
        int acc_sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (acc_sockfd < 0)
            ERR(EXIT_FAILURE,
                    "socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));

        /* this is needed in case you need to reopen it in a short time. */
        int reuse_addr = 1;
        int res = setsockopt(
                acc_sockfd,
                SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                &reuse_addr, sizeof reuse_addr);
        if (res < 0)
            ERR(EXIT_FAILURE,
                "setsockopt: %s\n", strerror(errno));

        res = bind(
                acc_sockfd,
                (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,
                sizeof server_addr);
        if (res < 0)
            ERR(EXIT_FAILURE,
                    "bind: %s\n", strerror(errno));

        /* 0 listen(2) will make the queue size 0, so only
         * connections that enter while server is accept()ing
         * them will enter */
        res = listen(acc_sockfd, -1);
        if (res < 0)
            ERR(EXIT_FAILURE,
                    "listen: %s\n", strerror(errno));

        struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
        client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        client_addr.sin_port = 0;
        socklen_t client_addr_sz = sizeof client_addr;

        int conn_sockfd = accept(
                acc_sockfd,
                (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,
                &client_addr_sz);
        if (res < 0)
            ERR(EXIT_FAILURE,
                "accept: %s\n", strerror(errno));

        close(acc_sockfd);

        char client_name[256];
        sockaddr2str(&client_addr,
                client_name, sizeof client_name);

        char buff[1024];
        printf("Connection from %s\n", client_name);

        FILE *f = fdopen(conn_sockfd, "r");
        if (!f)
            ERR(EXIT_FAILURE,
                "fdopen: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        int c;
        while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
            size_t n = snprintf(
                    buff, sizeof buff,
                    "[%02x]%s",
                    c,
                    c == '\n'
                        ? "\r\n"
                        : "");
            write(conn_sockfd, buff, n);
            if (c == '\033') break;
        }
        printf("Connection from %s ended\n", client_name);
        close(conn_sockfd);
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I didn't use this code and just looked at the flow and replicated a few things, and now my code works. Now the thing is I don't know what made it work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The (only) way to stop listening is to close the listening socket.  That will have no effect on the already accepted connection(s), so they can continue to be used.  To start listening again, you will need to open a new listening socket and bind it.  You'll probably need the SO_REUSEADDR option on the socket if you want to reopen the port before the TCP delay period has elapsed.

You could instead keep the listening socket around and simply not accept any more connections until you are finished with the first one, but that would not actually not listen -- any additional client that tried to connect would get a handshake from the kernel (so it would think it was connected) rather than a rejection.

A third possibility which is even more unlke what you are asking, but it probably a better design would be to keep the socket open and accept additional connections while you are processing the first connection, but then close these new connections right away with some kind of BUSY message.  Then clients could know at least something about what is going on.

It all depends on what you want to have clients see when they try to connect to a busy server.

Comment: Great. So 1 tried the first option in my case. While it seemed like working fine, after 2-3 times connecting and disconnecting the client, the binding of socket gives some error. So is the problem due to the port still in use? How can I rectify it? Also, I would like to know about the last option any resources?

Comment: If you want to rebind the socket soon after closing it, you'll need to set the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option.